# Last possible total solar elipse in the Earth's history

Tags: solar-eclipse

So the Moon is drifting away from Earth by 3.8 cm a year due to tidal interactions. With the Moon slowly receding from Earth, there will come a time when it no longer has sufficient angular size to cover the Sun completely. When will the last total solar eclipse occur?(when will the Moon's umbra no longer be able to project onto the Earth?)

Comment: In [about 600 million years](https://www.space.com/37627-total-solar-eclipse-earth-moon-alignment-future.html).

Comment: @PM 2Ring ah thankx! Question answered! :)

Comment: You have the answer to this question here: https://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-resources/astronomy-questions-answers/when-will-the-last-total-solar-eclipse-occur and here: https://www.space.com/37627-total-solar-eclipse-earth-moon-alignment-future.html.